# When using Python2.7 on App Engine, is it ok to reference per-request globals?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm using the Python2.7 runtime with threadsafe set to false in the manifest.

Am I safe to do

```
user = users.get_current_user()
```

once at the top of the script, in the global space, and reference it from within various handlers without any namespace problems?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is better to create a base class, add some functions there and then extend from base class all your handlers, because `get_current_user()` has to do with the request handler and make sense only there.

Here is an example:

```
import webapp2
from google.appengine.api import users

class BaseHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def get_user(self):
    #Maybe also adding some logic here or returning your own User model
    return users.get_current_user()


class MainPage(BaseHandler):
  def get(self):
    if self.get_user():
      self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
      self.response.out.write('Hello, ' + self.get_user().nickname())
    else:
      self.redirect(users.create_login_url(self.request.uri))
```

Comment: Big thanks Lipis. That's just what I needed. I've seen it done the way I mentioned in my question, but it didn't feel at all right. That's why I posted it here. Your approach is much nicer. Thanks.

Comment: @CarlSmith you can check a more advanced example.. that also creates an entity so you can store extra info for logged in users.. http://stackoverflow.com/a/11187580/8418

Comment: An even better way to do this would be to override the handler's initialize function and set an attribute to the result of calling `users.get_current_user`.