# store openid user in cookie google appengine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, cookies, openid

I am using OpenID as a login system for a google appengine website and I right now for every website I am just passing the user info to every page using `user = users.get_current_user()`

Would using a cookie to do this be more efficient?  (I know if would be easier that putting that in every single webpage) and is these any special way to do it with google appengine?  I already have a cookie counting visits but I would image it'll be a little different.

**Update**:  Could I do self.user = users.get_current_user() as a global variable and then pass in user=self.user on every page to have  access to that variable?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`users.get_current_user()` is actually reading the cookies so you don't need to do anything more to optimize it (you can easily verify it by deleting your cookies and then refreshing the page). Unless you want to store more information and have access to them without accessing the datastore on every request.

Comment: oh okay gotcha.  yes I would like to store more information but I suppose that is much more complex topic than can be explained in one post, correct?

Comment: @exployre you could check this answer.. to begin somewhere: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11187580/8418

Comment: okay thanks for that link.  I just updated it a bit is that possible?

Comment: @exployre The link is actually answering your second question.. just take it as is and you have it! But in general it's not ok to changing your question to something completely different.. ;) Please go through the FAQ for more (http://stackoverflow.com/faq)